# Verify YouTube channel ownership

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm working on a side project in which I need to verify if the channel belongs to a certain user based on his gmail account or any other parameter...this is basically to avoid fake accounts. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

yes,
follows a link with a youtube record explaining how to do a check, and you can get a lot of information about the channel[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)